# Class 'JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle' not found AppKernel

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am new to symfony and I have the following issue. 
**Class 'JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle' not found AppKernel** when running composer install command.

This is my AppKernel file:

```
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
        new FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle(),
        new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(),
    );
```

and this is my composer.json file.

```
{
"name": "gigi/api",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/metadata": ">=1.1.0,<1.3-dev",
    "jms/serializer": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "2.5.*@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.3.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have you done composer update ?

Comment: First run composer install, later add bundle to AppKernel

Comment: If you have already run  `composer install`, run `composer -vvv update` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the library is not available, so you have two options:

1. You can remove jmsserializer from composer.json and the use it as:

   composer require jms/serializer-bundle
2. I you want to keep the composer.json as it is you can run:

   composer update jms/serializer-bundle

Edit 1: Why this happens?
When you run `composer install`, it will get your composer.lock file and then install the dependencies, and as you can see symfony has some post-install/update scripts which relies on the symfony installation, which requires JMS serializer during its bootstrap.
In this case your composer.lock is outdated, so you need to either require or update the missing package.

I hope this helps you!